# Spring, почему возникает инспекция при подключении статичных файлов?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, freemarker

Я загружаю в Idea новый spring boot проект с настройками по умолчанию.
Подключаю в maven freemarker шаблонизатор.
Размещаю файл стилей в директории src/main/resources/static/css/main.css
Создаю контроллер и шаблон страницы, где подключаю этот файл стилей

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="hello-title">Hello!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Запускаю spring локально, в браузере файл стилей подгружается нормально.
Но в самой Idea путь подчеркивается как ошибочный (cannot resolve controller url)
и не работает автоподстановка
[image]

Comment: Неправильно указан адрес контроллера.

Comment: Это путь к статичному файлу, а не к контроллеру

Comment: Тогда пиши разумно. Станичные файлы обрабатываются сервлетом по умолчанию

Comment: У меня разумно так и написано. Я знаю как они обрабатываются, всё равно есть инспекция в idea и автоподстановка не работает

Comment: На инспекцию смотреть не надо, если ты добавищь туда урл перезапись фильтер то как идея будет находить маппинг?

Comment: Смысл в том чтобы idea подтягивала путь из ресурсов или Web Resource Directory.

Comment: Нет никакого смысла, в вэб приложении ссылка определяется в браузере.

Comment: Смысл есть - автоподстановка ускоряет разработку, а инспекция предотвращает ошибки/опечатки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас путь должен быть:

```
/static/css/main.css
```

и должна быть конфигурация

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Да в итоге пришёл к тому же решению, только конфигурацию вынес одной строчкой в файл application.properties -> spring.mvc.static-path-pattern = /static/**

Comment: @Александр так тоже можно? круто